# While loop and awk

Tags: bash

I am really not sure what I am missing

```
while [ $x -le $rowNumber ]
do
    rowNum$x=$(echo $rowName | awk -F ' ' '{print $x}')
    echo $rowNum$x
  x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

I am trying to create a rowNum[x] variable and assign them the results of the awk.

To make a valid example, assuming that $rowName is "Teo Mar Leo", rowNum1 should be "Teo", rowNum2 should be "Mar", rowNum3 should be "Leo"

At the moment I am getting just:

```
command not found
1
awk: illegal field $(), name "x"
```

Any idea?

Comment: That's not how you do dynamic variables in bash. And `awk` doesn't expand bash variables.

Comment: Use an array in the shell, not separate variables. `rowNum=($rowName)`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It looks like you got your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58035447/712526) (which is great!), but it also looks like there isn't much value here for future readers. I'm voting to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of "rowNum$x"

```
#!/bin/bash
rowNumber=3
x=0
while [ $x -le $rowNumber ]                                                     
do
    rowNum[$x]=$(echo $rowName | awk -F ' ' '{print $x}')
    echo $rowNum[$x]
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

What do you want to output by "'{print $x}'"?

"$x" is a bash variable, so it can not use in an awk script.